# Iterate over list of URLs and open each url with Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've a list of urls that I need to open with selenium, execute a script and extract certain links.

What I've done so far:

```
import re
from selenium import webdriver

###  Variables  ###

regexp = re.compile(r'\.[\.a-z]?[\.a-z]?\/')


###  Function  ###

def get_links():

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
    urls = ['https://www.url1.com.gt/', 'https://www.url2.com.co/', 'https://www.url3.com.pe']

    for url in urls:

        links = []
        target = []

        country = re.search(regexp, url).group()

        driver.get(url)
        driver.execute_script('return document.documentElement.outerHTML')

        hrefs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@href]')

        for href in hrefs:

            links.append(href.get_attribute('href'))

        for link in links:

            if 'string to check' in link:
                target.append(link)

        return country, target


country, target = get_links()
df = {country: target}
print(df)
```

The expected output is a dict with key: country and values: links that matches.

When I run this code, it executes correctly but it doesn't iterate over the list of URLs, it only opens and returns the data of the first URL.

If I put the return statement outside the for url in urls loop, it returns the data of the third URL.

How can I get the info of all the URLs in my list?

Comment: I think  `target`and `link` would be defined outside the for loop?. For each url in the loop, you are redefining `target` and `link` as empty lists.

Comment: @Andrex Same result if I do that. You get the data of the first URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `return` statement is defined within the for loop. As a result, it is expected that you only get the first URL since the function exits after the first loop. That said, have you tried what @Andrex suggested by defining `target` and `link` outside the for loop and un-indenting the `return county, target` so that it is outside of the main for loop? So the final code should look something like:

```py
def get_links():
    [SOME CODE]

    data = {}

    for url in urls:
        links = []
        target = []

        [SOME CODE]

        data[country] = target

    return data # Unindented
```

Hopefully this edited code helps you get the desired results.

Comment: Now it opens all the URLs but the return data matches only the last URL info. We're getting closer!

Comment: This might be because we are not collecting `country` information in the function. Put differently, we have `country = re.search(regexp, url).group()` but we don't really do anything with this information. So one approach may be to use a dictionary to store all of the `{country:target}' information and feel free to reach out if you're not sure what I mean.

Comment: That better! Now is scraping all the info of all the URLs. What I've done so it's better for me to read it is create a dataframe.
The only issue now is that it adds all the target values for each URL in each column.
Columns: {A: links from url1, url2 and url3}, {B: links from url1, url2 and url3}; {C: links from url1, url2 and url3}

Comment: Great! Glad to be of assistance.

Comment: Any final thoughts on how can I fix this?

Comment: Assuming that your dictionary looks something like `{ 'gt':[url1a, url2a, ..], 'co':[url1b, url2b,..]}`,

Comment: Yes, it looks something like that!

Comment: (Sorry, accidentally added comment before finishing). Assuming that your dictionary looks something like `data = { 'gt':[url1a, url2a, ..], 'co':[url1b, url2b,..]}`, what you can do is `df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')`. This will have it so that each row is the `country` and each column a `target` url. If you want to keep the list of urls as a single column, one way is to do add another `[]` to all of the values so it looks like: `data = { 'gt':[ [url1a, url2a, ..] ], 'co': [ [url1b, url2b,..] ]}`.